# How to harness auto-completion of strings?

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, list, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing an application in which I have to pass strings as parameters. Like these:

```
GetValue("InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.Description")
GetValue("InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.HardwareVersion")
CheckValue("InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.Manufacturer")
ScrambleValue("InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.ModelName")
DeleteValue("InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.ProcessStatus.Process.1")
```

The full list is about 10500 entries, and i tought that i'd be really lost in searching if i misspell something.

So I am trying to declare a namespace for every string segment (separated by ".") and declare the last  as a simple class that widens to a String of its FullName (except the base app namespace):

```
Class xconv
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal d As xconv) As String

        Dim a As String = d.GetType.FullName
        Dim b As New List(Of String)(Strings.Split(a, "."))
        Dim c As String = Strings.Join(b.Skip(1).ToArray, ".")

        Return c

    End Operator
End Class
```

So I'd have these declarations:

```
Namespace InternetGatewayDevice
        Namespace DeviceInfo
                Class Description
                    Inherits xconv
                End Class
        End Namespace
End Namespace
```

This way IntelliSense is more than happy to autocomplete that string for me.

Now I'd have to do this for every possible string, so I opted (in order to retain my sanity) to make a method that does that:

```
    Sub Create_Autocomlete_List()

        Dim pathlist As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\list.txt"))
        Dim def_list As New List(Of String)
        Dim thedoc As String = ""

        For Each kl As String In pathlist
            Dim locdoc As String = ""
            Dim el() As String = Strings.Split(kl, ".")
            Dim elc As Integer = el.Length - 1
            Dim elz As Integer = -1
            Dim cdoc As String
            For Each ol As String In el
                elz += 1

                If elz = elc Then
                    locdoc += "Class " + ol + vbCrLf + _
                        "Inherits xconv" + vbCrLf + _
                        "End Class"
                Else
                    locdoc += "Namespace " + ol + vbCrLf
                    cdoc += vbCrLf + "End Namespace"
                End If

            Next

            locdoc += cdoc
            thedoc += locdoc + vbCrLf + vbCrLf

        Next

        IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\start_list_dot_net.txt", thedoc)

    End Sub
```

The real problem is that this is HORRIBLY SLOW and memory-intense (now i dot a OutOfMemory Exception), and I have no idea on how Intellisense would perform with the (not available in the near future) output of the Create_Autocomlete_List() sub.

I believe that it would be very slow.

So the real questions are: Am I doing this right? Is there any better way to map a list of strings to auto-completable strings? Is there any "standard" way to do this?

What would you do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how Visual Studio is going to perform with thousands of classes, but your `Create_Autocomlete_List` method can be optimized to minimize memory usage by not storing everything in memory as you build the source code.  This should also speed things up considerably.

It can also be simplified, since nested namespaces can be declared on one line, e.g. `Namespace First.Second.Third`.

```
Sub Create_Autocomlete_List()

    Using output As StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText("D:\start_list_dot_net.txt")
        For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadLines("D:\list.txt")
            Dim lastDotPos As Integer = line.LastIndexOf("."c)
            Dim nsName As String = line.Substring(0, lastDotPos)
            Dim clsName As String = line.Substring(lastDotPos + 1)
            output.Write("Namespace ")
            output.WriteLine(nsName)
            output.Write("    Class ")
            output.WriteLine(clsName)
            output.WriteLine("        Inherits xconv")
            output.WriteLine("    End Class")
            output.WriteLine("End Namespace")
            output.WriteLine()
        Next
    End Using

End Sub
```

Note the use of `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines`, which returns an `IEnumerable` instead of an array.  Also note that the output is written directly to the file, instead of being built in memory.

**Note** Based on your sample data, you may run into issues where the last node is not a valid class name. e.g. `InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.ProcessStatus.Process.1` - `1` is not a valid class name in VB.NET.  You will need to devise some mechanism to deal with this - maybe some unique prefix that you could strip in your widening operator.

I'm also not sure how usable the resulting classes will be, since presumably you would need to pass an instance to the methods:

```
GetValue(New InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.Description())
```

It seems like it would be nicer to have `Shared` strings on a class:

```
Namespace InternetGatewayDevice
    Class DeviceInfo
        Public Shared Description As String = "Description"
        Public Shared HardwareVersion As String = "HardwareVersion"
        ' etc.
    End Class
End Namespace
```

So you could just reference those strings:

```
GetValue(InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.Description)
```

However, I think that would be a lot harder to generate without creating name clashes due to the various levels of nesting.